# Why do I get an "undeclared" error in the main function?

Tags: c

My function won't compile as it keeps saying "x is undeclared" in the main function (can't be modified), what am I doing wrong?

```
int main(){
  printf("\nsquare root test 1: enter a number\n");
  scanf("%f",&x);
  printf("root(%.2f) = %.4f\n", x, squareRoot(x, .001));

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

For completeness, this is the implementation of the `squareRoot` function:

```
float squareRoot(float value, float error){
    float estimate;
    float quotient;
    estimate = 1;
    float difference = abs(value - estimate * estimate);
    while (difference > error){
        quotient = value/estimate;
        estimate = (estimate + quotient)/2;
        difference = abs(value - estimate * estimate);
    }
    return difference;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare x first to use it inside main function

```
float x;
```

Like this with in the scope or you can declare globally

```
int main(){
  float x;
  printf("\nsquare root test 1: enter a number\n");
  scanf("%f",&x);
  printf("root(%.2f) = %.4f\n", x, squareRoot(x, .001));

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, if `main()` cannot be modified, then `x` needs to be declared at file scope.

Comment: @H2CO3 what do you mean by `main()` can't be modified?

Comment: @icepack Read the question. "in the main function (can't be modified), [...]"

Answer (score 1):

If x cannot be declared in the main function, then declare it in a global scope,

```
float x;

int main( ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
  float x ; /* You missed this :-D */
  printf("\nsquare root test 1: enter a number\n");
  scanf("%f",&x);
  printf("root(%.2f) = %.4f\n", x, squareRoot(x, .001));

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```